# Biztalk binding export show status

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I am using Biztalk 2006R2.

I would like to know how to include the binding status (enlist/unenlist/start/stop) in the binding exported xml.

Comment: I don't actually believe that this is possible - we have taken a screenshot in the past prior changing config so we can re-create this config later. Simple, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

The binding files do contain that information already.

1. For Orchestrations it is called State (Default, Unenlisted, Enlisted, Started) see [Service (Services Node)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd801283.aspx)
2. For Receive Locations it is called Enabled and is a boolean, see [ReceiveLocation (ReceiveLocations Node)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd801985.aspx)
3. For send ports there is also a property, can't recall what it is at the moment.

Comment: I found that in receive location, there is a xml element called "Enable". But in sendportgroup and sendport, there is no such xml element. Therefore, i do not know whether the sendportgroup or sendport is enabled or not.

Comment: Yes, looking at it again, I can't find it for the send port or send port group either.  Hover you can write scripts that use WMI to retrieve these if necessary.